# $\prod (1+a_k)$ converges $\Leftrightarrow \sum a_k$ converges if $a_k\geq 0$ or $a_k\leq 0$ for each k.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Basically the title. I'mo working on a proof right now and I'm not quite sure where to begin. I thought about writing out the $n$th partial product and then taking logarithms but that doesn't get rid of the $1$ in each of the terms. Just a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful. Basically I have to prove that if $a_k\leq 0$ or $a_k\geq 0$ then:

$$\prod_k^\infty c_k=\prod_k^\infty(1+a_k)=C\Leftrightarrow \sum_k^\infty a_k=S$$

Where $C$ is the limit of the $n$th partial product and $S$ is the limit of the $n$th partial sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\log\left(\prod_{k=1}^N(1+a_k)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^N\log(1+a_k)$. Besides, $\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=0\implies\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+a_k)}{a_k}=1$.

Comment: Does the sum $\log(1+a_k)$ converging imply that the sum of $a_k$ also converges? if so how? Because this is what I originally did but I couldn't figure out where to go from here

Comment: Yes, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\log(1+a_k)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^k$ converges. This follows from the comparison test and that's why I mentioned in my answer that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+a_k)}{a_k}=1$.